# Python logging through uwsgi, supervisor, and Docker

Tags: python, docker, nginx, logging

I have a Python REST API running in a Docker container, behind uUWSGI, which is managed by Supervisord. Running the app locally, my logs appear in the terminal how I want them, but I can't replicate this in a container/production environment to my syslog server. I've been through lots of SO threads, but no combination of flags seems to get my logging working.

My Python logging code, in main.py:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(request_id)s %(module)s:%(levelname)s %(message)s')
handler = logging.StreamHandler() # have tried forcing this to stderr/stdout
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.addFilter(AppFilter())

application.app.logger.handlers.clear()
application.app.logger.addHandler(handler)
application.app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
application.app.logger.debug('application starting...')
```

The above code works fine for local terminal output, here's what I have tried configuring the other software/services to:

uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = ./src
wsgi-file = main.py
pythonpath = ./src

master = true
processes = 4
threads = 2

uid = nginx
gid = nginx
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
chown-socket = nginx:nginx
chmod-socket = 664

plugins = python3
```

supervisord.conf:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
user=root

[program:uwsgi]
command=/usr/sbin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini --die-on-term --log-master
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

And finally, the Docker daemon is configured as `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "log-driver": "syslog",
  "log-opts": {
    "syslog-address": "tcp://syslog_server_ip_address:514", # IP redacted for stackoverflow
    "tag": "my_api"
  }
}
```

As there's quite a few levels the logs have to pass through, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. My syslog server **does** receive a log for each request, which I think are raw uWSGI logs, but I can't get any of my Python logging code to work in the container environment.

The log that does work looks like:

```
host1.net my_api[1753]: [pid: 12|app: 0|req: 2/2] ip.ip.ip.ip () {36 vars in 432 bytes} [Mon Jan 13 07:58:43 2020] GET /v1/test => generated 25256 bytes in 16 msecs (HTTP/1.0 200) 2 headers in 74 bytes (1 switches on core 1)
```

Any help/pointers appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Supervisord introduces a layer of indirection that could cause some problems here.  Can you remove this, and run the two programs in two separate containers?

Comment: Running them in separate containers would require a bit of re-architecting, would it be worth trying to get supervisord to log to a file if you think that's the issue? Then I could check that 'layer' to see if the logs are getting past uwsgi, so to speak?

Comment: @DavidMaze I redirected supervisord stdout/stderr logs to a file within the container, and that seems to be working - I can see my Python logs - so it seems the issue is not with the Python code, or UWSGI, but with either Supervisord or Docker?

Comment: `docker logs` and the other Docker-native log mechanisms only include stdout and stderr of the main container process, they will never republish logs from files in the container.

Comment: @DavidMaze My understanding (or guess) was that if supervisord stdout_logfile works for writing to a log file within the container (which it does), if I sent that output to /dev/stdout then it would work. This obviously doesn't seem to work, am I missing something?

Comment: Removing the logging config from supervisord.conf makes no logs from uwsgi appear at all, so *some* logs get to my syslog server, but not the ones from my code. I have tried a supervisord-stdout Python plugin but that appears to be broken with the latest version.